# Como faço para puxar os vendedores em um combobox para depois filtrar a venda por vendedor?

Tags: c#

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
VENDAS
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VENDA_ID | VENDA_RAZAOSOCIAL | VENDA_CIDADE | VENDA_DATA | VENDA_FORPAGAMENTO | VENDA_VENDEDOR | VENDA_VALOR
```

E utilizo o seguinte `SELECT` para selecionar as vendas:

```
SELECT * FROM VENDAS WHERE VENDA_DATA>=@dataIni and VENDA_DATA<=@dataFinal and VENDA_VENDEDOR = @vendedor
```

Ja tenho o INSERT , agora preciso saber como consigo puxar o vendedor para que ele apareço no combobox e assim eu possa clicar em um botao para filtrar

Alguem pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Você pode usar os elementos do System.Data para puxar tudo para uma dataTable e colocar a propriedade DataSource do combobox para buscar neste DataTable

Comment: seria como ?  using system data ?

Comment: Web Forms, WPF, XAML, MVC... O que você está usando?

Comment: estou usando windows forms c#

Comment: estou usando windows forms c#

Comment: Alguem poderia me ajudar ?